# JPA: How to create one Query to many datasources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two datasources in my app i need to create join query with this data source,

How i should do this correctly ?

I tried to use Critera Api but not working, Entity Manager too...

Entity for one datasource is in **folder1**, second in **folder2**

In repository query like below don't working

```
SELECT t1 FROM mySql t1
JOIN com.test.test.test.model.entity.folder2.sqlServer t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
WHERE t2.postCode <> ''
```

Summary:

Two datasources

Entity in two different folder for each,

Create Join query

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can't. JPA translates any query you provide, no matter if it is Criteria, JPQL or SQL into a SQL statement which then gets executed in the database, so it can only reference stuff available in that database.

And even when both data sources reference the same database, JPA doesn't know about it, because it does know only one half of the entities.

If you want to query data from multiple databases you have to use either separate queries. Or you have to make the tables available in one database through technologies like [Oracle Database Links](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm).

Comment: Could you give me some example of this ?,
I have mysql and sql server DB,
i'm a begginer